# JS | Получаю с бека инопланетные иероглифы вместо excel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xml

Ситауция такая. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы пользователь на клиенте мог скачать exel файл, который отдаёт бекендер

Получаю их просто - через axios

Но вместо чего-то читаемого, я получаю непонятные иероглифы. *(скриншот приложил)*

> Так вот, что мне с этим делать и что это вообще такое?)

Есть у меня подоздрения, что я должен как-то это форматировать, но абсолютно не понимаю как, потому что не хватает понимания, что это за иероглифы

[image: Иероглифы]

Comment: Простите, а что вы хотите получить? Вы получаете нормальный Excel-файл. Если это таблица, то вам нужно "прочесть" её и распарсить значения.

Comment: Используйте `exceljs` для парсинга значений из таблицы.

Comment: Если нужно чтоб пользователь скачал, то проще сделать ссылку на файл, который откроется в новой вкладке, ИМХО